# Photon gas into a Black hole

Tags: black-holes, photons, gravitational-collapse

Can a photon gas have so much energy that it collapse into a black hole just like a regular star?

Answer (score 0):

After some thought I think yes it can. If we have enough photon energy concentrated in a area, it can create a black hole.